# Why this legacy SA has access to resources

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-iam

I am failing to understand why a particular Google Cloud service account has access to resources in a specific namespace inside GKE.

There seem to be no evidence it should have access. Alternatively, it could be me who's misinterpreting IAM / RBAC integration.

**Is there any logs I could check to see what access policies are in use inside Kubernetes when this SA attempts to access specific resources in it?**

For context, I have this service account:

```
github@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

The account is assigned the following:

- on **Google Cloud IAM** level, I have `roles/container.developer` assigned to the said Service Account,
- on **Kubernetes (GKE)** level, I have a role + role binding created:

  ```
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Role
  metadata:
    name: ci-cd
    namespace: default
  rules:
  - apiGroups:
    - apps
    resourceNames:
    - my-backend
    resources:
    - deployments
    verbs:
    - list
    - watch
    - patch
    - get
  ```

  ```
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  kind: RoleBinding
  metadata:
    name: ci-cd
    namespace: default
  roleRef:
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: Role
    name: ci-cd
  subjects:
  - apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: User
    name: github@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
    namespace: default
  ```

This SA can perform `patch` on `deployment` as expected:

```
kubectl auth can-i patch deployment/my-backend \
  --namespace default \
  --as github@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
yes
```

What's confusing, and what I am failing to explain to myself, is why this account's attempts to patch a deployment with a different name in different namespace are successful (as observed), which I am able to cross-check by confirming with Cloud Audit Logs:

```
insertId: 10f277c5-041c-4e61-afa6-5ca669393a50
labels:
  authorization.k8s.io/decision: allow
  authorization.k8s.io/reason: access granted by IAM permissions.
logName: projects/my-project/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity
operation:
  first: true
  id: 10fc17c5-041c-4e61-afa6-5ca661793a50
  last: true
  producer: k8s.io
protoPayload:
  '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog
  authenticationInfo:
    principalEmail: github@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  authorizationInfo:
  - granted: true
    permission: io.k8s.apps.v1.deployments.patch
    resource: apps/v1/namespaces/review-apps/deployments/my-backend-5005
  methodName: io.k8s.apps.v1.deployments.patch
  request:
# ...
```

**...all the while this returns `no`**:

```
kubectl auth can-i patch deployment/my-backend-5005 \
  --namespace review-apps \
  --as github@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
no
```

I am at a loss here. Send help.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but access management on GKE, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf], [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/), or contact the [GKE support](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was me misinterpreting a item 2 from "[Applications within Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication#applications_within)" section of "[Authenticating to the Kubernetes API server](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication)" article.

Particularly, I found this wording to be confusing:

> You **can also use** RBAC to grant the IAM...

My mistake was that I've implemented suggestions from the item entirely, e.g. both granted an IAM permission AND added a Kubernetes-level RBAC. Because of this, I observed the following:

- due to IAM permission, the Service Account can effectively perform actions to most objects across namespaces, disregarding any kubernetes-level RBAC rules,
- due to RBAC policy I have, I had results coming from `kubectl auth can-i` that contradicted previous item,

I wish the *You **can also use** RBAC to grant the IAM...* could be reworded to *Alternatively, use RBAC to grant the IAM...". Filed a documentation update request for Google Cloud for that page.